# Neo4j design performance: Do I have to avoid large node degrees?

Tags: graph, neo4j, graph-databases

I'm in the middle of designing a data model to be implemented using Neo4j. Is is about a transportation system, that has some stations, having some vehicles traveling between them.

There is a huge amount of travels from some stations, say one million each month. So I want to know is there any performance penalty in case of having some nodes with millions of edges coming out of them? Is it better to keep degrees lower with some design tricks (and probably making design a little worse)?

Answer (score 1):

Relationship degrees really matter most when they're traversed, so expansions that are traversing any relationship type and direction, or the type (and direction) of relationship that has a high number of degrees.

So if there are 100k :TRAVELS_TO relationships to a specific location, 100 :VISITED relationships to the location, and only 1 :TRAVELS_TO relationship *from* that location, then you'll only be paying a high cost when traversing those :TRAVELS_TO relationships to the location. If you're traversing relationships of a different type and/or direction, you won't be paying any higher cost because of the 100k other relationships.

So diversifying your types and/or directions can certainly help out.

You may want to check Max De Marzi's blog for his approaches when [constructing a flight/airtravel graph](https://maxdemarzi.com/2017/05/24/flight-search-with-neo4j/), you may find good approaches to use here.